# Using WFS Layer as a baselayer

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, wfs

I've looked around the net and I've looked for examples, but I just can't seem to find a way to make a WFS layer be the baselayer. I set up the projection the right way and I set isBaseLayer: true . When I open my map it's empty. Only the controls are present and there is a white map.

Could it be that it's simply not supported (but since there is the option to set it as isBaseLayer: true, this wouldn't make no sense) ?!

Thanks for your help.

P.S.: The only thing I've changed can be seen inside of the code.

EDIT:

Here is my code:

```js
function myInit2(){

    var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
    var world = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -89, 180, 89).transform(
            geographic, mercator
    );
    var deutschl = new OpenLayers.Bounds(5, 50, 15, 56).transform(
            geographic, mercator
    );

    var dortmund= new OpenLayers.LonLat(7.46, 51.51).transform(
            geographic, mercator
    );

    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map_location", {
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(5, 50, 15, 56).transform(
                geographic, mercator)
    });

    //var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    // this was the old baselayer

    var baseL = new OpenLayers.Layer.WFS(
                "Bundesländer",
                "http://vs136213:8080/geoserver/wfs",
                {typename: "BitmarckKarten:land_shp"},
                {isBaseLayer: true, extractAttributes: true, styleMap: myStyleMapL}
        );      


    //initialize the base layer here
    //map.addLayers([osm]);
    //old add of baselayer

    map.addLayers([baseL]);  

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
    // map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());        
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()); 
    map.setCenter(dortmund, 6);        
    getDivInfos();

};
```

Comment: can you post a link to your code?

Comment: I guess your problem is related to the use of openlayers? Is your layer displaying when you remove *isBaseLayer* option?

Comment: If i remove it or set it to false, all i get is the same empty map, but now im unable to see the mouse position on the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just made a quick test http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver/www/wfs/wfs-baselayer.html and you can use a WFS as a baselayer. I suspect your problem is probably a [Same-Origin problem](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/request.html) - check with FireBug that the response to the request is there (if it works when you open it in a new tab but fails in the map then you need a proxy).

Comment: I think i found the solution to the problem by finding this example which didnt cross my eye until today http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/all-overlays.html

Comment: Actually that is the opposite of the question you asked. As my solution shows there is no problem adding a WFS as a baselayer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the definition of *myStyleMapL* style. Are you sure the issue comes form isBaseLayer.

Could you try that :

```js
var baseL = new OpenLayers.Layer.WFS(
            "Bundesländer",
            "http://vs136213:8080/geoserver/wfs",
            {typename: "BitmarckKarten:land_shp"},
            {isBaseLayer: true}
    );
```

By the way, you should have a look on firebug to see if any error message is displayed.

Comment: You cant see it because the code is much more big, so if i had to post the whole code it would basicly blast stackexchange away :D . its defined and there are no firebug errors. i should have mentioned that, sorry for that.

Edit: your edit doesnt change it. but it makes the mouseposition work, opposed to isBaseLayer: false.

Comment: And have you tested if it's not a projection error? You should give a try to zoomToMaxExtent() to see if your layer is not lost somewhere. Or directly to the that specific layer extent